# Why conversion from Bitmap to EmguCV Image not working?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, emgucv

I am trying to convert Bitmap to EmguCV Image to load my pictures in ImageBox.

But I got this error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'Emgu.CV.IImage'

Then I tried the below syntax after doing some research in SO:

```
Bitmap masterImage = (Bitmap)pbxMaster.Image;
Image<Gray, Byte> normalizedMasterImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(masterImage);
```

But got these errors:

1. The name 'pbxMaster' does not exist in the current context.
2. A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ContourAnalysisDemo.MainForm.masterImage'

What did I miss here?